How can I make a custom utility library with functions that will be callable from windows cmd?
How can I make a custom utility library with cmd/batch functions that will be callable from a windows cmd terminal?
You can make functions in a batch file, for instance:
@echo off
goto :main

:say_hello
  echo Hello world!
goto :eof

:main
  call :say_hello


However, trying to call the function from cmd (after running the batch file in the same terminal) gives me Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script..
The other way I know how to do this is to make each "function" its own batch file. But that is kind of ugly in the sense that if every function, no matter how tiny, has to have its own batch file, then it can lead to a huge number of files! I'd rather have all my cmd utility functions in a single file of a few hundred to a few thousand lines, than to have the code scattered among lots of tiny files.
In Linux, the way to do this is instead of running a shell script, you source it to expose the functions. Essentially I'm looking for the Windows equivalent of doing that.

PowerShell is the way this works in Windows. You can import modules into PowerShell sessions. You can call modules at the start of scripts if you want to run it in a script.

You were punctual, writing two words to call a function does not apply to your case, I think I understood it differently, language barriers, it happens a lot, my fault. Forgive..

@Io-oI You don't have to delete your answer. It may still help people who stumble upon the post in their searches.

It will hardly help, responses out of context attract negative votes, and thus become ignored

@echo off

if "%~1" == "" =;( 
     goto :main 
    );= else goto :%~1

:say_hello
  echo Hello world!
goto :eof

:main
  call :say_hello


Call your bat arg with argument to execute your function:
>file.bat say_hello
Hello world!


To call your bat during execution itself:
call "%~dpnx0" say_hello 



This is being done in this issue to provide "animation" in the progression bar.

See this answer too: VBScript redirects user to label

This is somewhat helpful, but not precisely what I'm looking for. It does achieve the wish to gather the functions in a single file. However, your solution is more akin to having a single big function with a switch case that uses the first argument to choose the case. It is less concise, less user friendly because it requires always at least two words to be typed, rather than one (the name of the function itself). By the way, what does the =; and ;= do in your snippet?

Make a custom utility library calledable?
If you don't like lots of bat files, you can combine them into one file.
You can use %* (or %1, %2, %3) to determine which section to be executed.
This an example:
@echo off
:: MyLib.bat
setlocal
Set Arg=%*
:: Set Arg=%1
Goto :%Arg%

:One
echo this One
goto :end 

:Two
echo this Two
goto :end 

:Three
echo this Three
goto :end  

:Four
echo this Four
goto :end 

:Five
echo this Five 

:end
pause
endlocal
exit

Then, you can execute one of them with command:
Both from Commandline or a bat file
MyLib.bat One
MyLib Four

The Result:
CMD: MyLib Four
this Four
Press any key to continue . . .


So that it can be executed from any location, the file must be placed in %Path%, such as System32 or %Windir%, or you make your own custom path using Set Path... or SetX Path....

Thanks for the answer, but this is not precisely the solution I was looking for. This is equivalent to (if you're familiar with C/C++) a large function with a switch case on the first argument to determine which piece of code to execute. The main reason not to do it this way, is that it requires at least two words to be typed (the file name plus an id for the function), rather than one (just the function name). I want the commands to be concise and easy to type for everyday use. I would like to know if there is a way to expose the function names and call them directly from the cmd terminal.

The solution I found that is the closest to what I'm looking for (so far), is to make macros, which are essentially environment variables that contain commands. Then you call it like %myfunc% arg1 arg2 arg3. It's still a bit ugly to have to write % around it, so all in all it's not that much better than your method.

-@QwertYuiop I think, if the script placed on Path, don't need %myfunc% .... Enought with myfunc ...

The solution I found that is the closest to what I'm looking for, is to make macros, which are essentially environment variables that contain commands. You source it by running your script to set those variables, and then you can call it from the cmd terminal like %myfunc% arg1 arg2 arg3, see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html for full explanation.
It's still a bit ugly to have to write %'s around the function names, so it's arguably not that much better than the solutions proposed by @Io-oI (deleted answer) and @Mr.Key7.
